# Verificar se contém caracteres na string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando uso `teste.length` ele me retorna o tamanho, mas como faço para verificar se não contém nenhum caractere?

Por exemplo:

```
var teste = (como se o usuário tivesse clicado **2x** no **enter/espaço**);
```

Logo `teste.length` vai me retornar **2**, mas na realidade não contém nenhum caractere.

Gostaria que quando não tivesse nada, me retornasse 0.

Comment: Seu conceito está errado, se não contém caracteres o tamanho é 0. Tem tem espaços então tem caracteres. Se você não quer contar certos tipos de caracteres teria que definir muito bem quais são eles. Inclusive é possível o usuário colar algo que não tem caracteres visíveis e não ser espaço. E aí? pra mim ou define o problema direito e acha uma solução real ou fica gambiarra de qualquer forma.

Comment: Acho que o colega apenas se expressou mal, ele quis dizer que para a motivação dele, espaço em branco não seria um caractere válido. Mas você tem razão, espaço é sim um caractere válido.

Comment: @Jaffe.David só que precisa expressar com exatidão pra ter um resultado exato. Lei todo o comentário, há ambiguidade até se falar em espaço. Em geral as pessoas não entendem o que elas não veem, e caracteres não imprimíveis são válidos e não costuma interessar, não é só espaço. Faz de qualquer jeito aí um diga falha e a pessoa não sabe porque. Conceituar tudo direito é importante pra fazer certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o `trim()`.

`stringExemplo = stringExemplo.trim();` ela remove os espaços em branco. Você pode utilizar o `str.replace` também.

Comment: a bronca do `replace` seria ele alterar também os espaços internos da _string_ (que não sei se é o caso).

Answer (score 2):

Use o [`trim()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp), assim serão desconsiderados espaços no início e no fim da *string*.

```
var teste = string_usada.trim();
```